# How can I have the same title for all images in a set using FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am creating a gallery using [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net). What I want to do is describe a work (whatever kind) and apparently all images are related to the work as is. Just as alternate views to the same subject.

How can I have a title for all of them? I know that fancybox gets the title from the `<a>` element. One obvious solutions it to have the same title for all objects. This ofcource is one dummy solution.

**edit:**
Data is loaded using Ajax and there might be multiple galleries per page that have alternate titles

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this post is tagged PHP.

In your js -

```
$('a.whatever').fancybox({title:"Set Title Here"});
```

This should force the title, supposing that all `fancybox` instances are called from the same anchor? Would be more helpful if you could post your HTML / JS

Comment: In that case, the only way you can really do it is by having alternate titles unless you have a seperate onclick function for each gallery with the method specified above. I guess you could give the gallery wrapper `div` a title and use the click function to get that, want an example?

Comment: yes please! I can't figure out a way to tell fancybox how to get parent's title.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T4HJv/1/ - obviously won't work on the fiddle but try to port it over to your code as best as possible